# How can I have the BooleanField in django set to the value picked from the model?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am able to correctly save the value of "Private" in the model. But, when I open the Edit Page, it's always set to unchecked irrespective of the value being True or False.

```
# from forms.py
class MyEditForm(forms.Form)
    title = forms.CharField(
        label='Title',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 64})
        )
    private = forms.BooleanField(
        label='Private',
        required=False,
    )

# from models.py
class MyData(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    private = models.BooleanField()

# from views.py
def save_page(request)
    try:
        mydata = MyData.objects.get(
            private=private
        )
        title = mydata.title
        private = mydata.private
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    form = MyEditForm({
        'title': title,
        'private': private
    })
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you get the `MyData` object by the private attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a ModelForm not a Form.  Then when you instantiate the ModelForm set the instance to your model.  This will also save you from needing to duplicate the form fields since django will auto generate the form fields based on the model.

```
foo = Foo.objects.get(id=foobar)
form = YourForm(instance=foo)
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I searched for ModelForm and found a good example to proceed and investigate.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/